# How to use One procedure output variable data into another procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have one requirement in which I have to design two procedure.First procedure will generate one output variable value and then second procedure will use to do its task. I am giving same kind of scenario in below code

```
create procedure existingProc(

begin
    insert statementprogramming statement

);


create procedure MyProc(

begin
    call existingProc();
    -- Exsisting procedure return some value 
    -- and this value is used in MyProc 

commit;
);
```

In the above code existingProc is already there in the system and I can not change it. IN the procedure transaction is begin but not committed. This procedure generate one value as Output param and MyProc will used this value. 
I want that after executing the existingProc, MyProc procedure should get the value, but it is not happening and it is giving null.
what should i do here, Please help me. I can not share the code that why giving scenario.

Comment: Your procedure declarations are broken.  Please fix them.  The basic pattern is `create [or replace] procedure procName(param [in|out] type[, ...]) as begin ... end;`  You are missing your parameter lists, the closing parenthesis and the is/as key words.  Additionally you have `begin` statements without matching `end;` statements.

Comment: why dont you put the values you want in a temp table , then retreive it in the another procedure ?

Comment: @Moudiz Otherthan this there is not way to manage the transaction manually. Because in my case its not possible.

Comment: @Sentinel, Its not a complete code, by using this template i am just trying to create scenario.

Comment: @Naveen can you explain please a simpe scenario so we can help you?

Comment: @Naveen, that's obvious, but you indicate that the `existingProc` has an output variable, but you don't give any indication of it in your sample pseudo code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help clarify how to use the output parameters from one procedure in another procedure?

```
create procedure ExistingProc(output1 out number) is
begin
  insert into someTable values ('some values')
  RETURNING someCol INTO output1;
end;

create procedure MyProc(args ....) is
  Result1 number;  --output from existingProc
begin
  ExistingProc(result1);
  -- Use Result1 as needed
  Update stuff ...
  where id = Resutl1;
  commit;
end;
```